# Is there some way to get path parameters in @SecureSocial.SecuredAction authorization implementation?

Tags: playframework-2.1, securesocial

I'm new to playframework and trying to use securesocial for authentication & authorization in my web app.
I need to add custom authorization to my controller, that checks if current user is creator of entity, that he is trying to view or edit.

```
@SecureSocial.SecuredAction(authorization = OwnerCanEdit.class, params = {"id"})
```

routes:

```
GET  /projects/edit/:id   @controllers.ProjectsController.edit(id)
```

To make this I need to pass entity id from request path. 
Is there some way to get/pass path parameter in class implementing Authorization interface?

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to do it. This is a valid use case and should be covered. I'll keep this in mind to improve the API.